# The time complexity of integer multiplication by FFT without any sophistication.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, fast-fourier-transform

David Harvey and Joris van der Hoeven proved at this year that the product of two integers whose bit length is $O(n)$ can be computed in $O(n\log n)$.

I've heard that the optimal complexity of multiplication has been believed to be $O(n \log n)$ 30 years simply because the FFT can be computed in $O(n \log n)$.

Now I have question.

Considering two integer $A$ and $B$ such that

$$A=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i 10^i \ (0\leq a_i <10),$$
$$B=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_i 10^i \ (0\leq b_i <10).$$

We want to calculate the product of $A$ and $B$.
By FFT, product of two polynomials,$A'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i x^i$ and $B'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_i x^i$ can be computed in $O(n\log n)$.

Then, just calculating the increasing of digit from the lower digit.

What is the time complexity of this algorithm? Apparently, the upper bound of time complexity is $O(n^2)$ when $n$ digit increasing happens at every digit. However, I cannot construct such case.